# Bison Expression Parsing Failure c++

Tags: expression, bison, bisonc++

This is my Bison Parser Code.

```
statement
    : compound_statement
    | expression_statement
    ;



expression_statement
    : ';'
    | expression ';'                        {cout<<"expr found\n";}
    ;

expression
     : number_expression                    {cout << "number expression\n";}
    ;

number_expression
    : number_arith_expression               {cout << "arith expression\n";}
    ;

number_arith_expression

    : number_idenfiers
    | number_constants
    | number_arith_expression number_arith_expression '+'   { cout<<"found\n";}
    | number_arith_expression number_arith_expression '-'   {}

    ;

number_idenfiers
    : PPNUMVAR                                                  {}
    | PPSYSNUMVAR                                               {}
    ;

number_constants
    : PPFLOAT                                                   {}
    ;
```

I gave Expression as

> 23 23 +;

My result is :

> found
>
> arith expression
>
> number expression
>
> Line Number : 1 .. parse error

Why It doesn't parse at expression_statment ? It doesn't parse the SEMICOLON. What Should I change to work with semicolon?

Comment: The most likely is that your lexical scanner isn't correctly returning the semicolon token, but it's hard to know without seeing the scanner. Instead of scattering printfs into your parser, why don't you use bison's built-in debugging facilities, which will give you a lot more information including which tokens it actually sees. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Enabling-Traces

Answer (score 0):

According to your grammar a valid addition expression would be two expressions followed by a `+`, but your input has the `+` in the middle.

Comment: Oops! Sorry. Mistakenly I entered it. It is a postfix Expression. Now I corrected that Question.